# Once typing starts, check input box every 3 seconds until the user stops typing - how?

Tags: jquery

Here is my attempt in jquery that kind of works but something is going wrong which i cannot work out. For example, if I type 'ff', and then add another two 'ff's afterwards too many console logs occur - difficult to explain, but if you run the code and experiment, too many console.logs are getting called.

```
$("#search-input").keyup(function () {
        var thisVal = $(this).val();
        if(thisVal!=''){
            function checker (v){
                if($("#search-input").val() !=v){
                    setTimeout(function(){checker($("#search-input").val() )}, 3000);
                }
                else{
                    console.log($("#search-input").val());
                }
            }
            setTimeout(function(){checker(thisVal)}, 3000);

        }
    });
```

search-input is just the input box. I actually plan to make an ajax call instead of console.logging but if I can get the above working that will put me well on the way.

Comment: Are you going to implement an _username availability_ check?

Comment: No, this is just a simple ajax search. I just don't want the search to be triggered every time they enter a new character, as the front end of my web app is written with a lot of javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The previous timeout has to be cleared, before setting a new one:

```
var timeout;
$("#search-input").keyup(function () {
    var thisVal = $(this).val();
    if (thisVal) {
        function checker(v) {
            if($("#search-input").val() != v ){
                clearTimeout(timeout);
                timeout = setTimeout(function() {
                    checker($("#search-input").val() );
                }, 3000);
            } else {
                console.log($("#search-input").val());
            }
        }
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(function(){checker(thisVal)}, 3000);
    }
});
```

Comment: Rob, I tried that but the problem still persists. The first couple of console logs work fine and then it does 3 console logs in a row with the same input value output. e.g. adding 3 'f's in a second causes the same value to console.logged several times. Any ideas? Btw, timeout has to be prefixed with var for the code to work in case you try and run it. Thanks.

Comment: @Hardworker No, it should **not** be prefixed with `var` to get it to work. That's what breaking your code. By prefixing `var`, you're declaring a variable in the current scope. When `var` is omitted, the value is assigned to the closest declaration of the variable, which is the one which was prefixed with `var`. Literally copy-paste the code from my answer, it will work.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your code works perfectly and I am choosing your answer.

Answer (score 4):

A simpler way, perhaps, is to just keep deferring the check until they've stopped typing for a period of time.  That is, if the timer is running clear it and reschedule the check for later. If the timer ever expires (i.e., they user has not typed in the box for the scheduled time), then perform the check.  Three seconds is probably too long for this.  You might want 500ms or so.

```
var timer; // external so it's value is held over all instances of the timer function
$('#search-input').on('keyup',function() {
     if (timer) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
     }
     timer = setTimeout(function() {
         // perform your check
         console.log($('#search-input').val());
     },500);
});
```